# String time passed from AsyncTask class variable not converting into date object in android but it works fine when i hard code the sting

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

String time passed from `AsyncTask` class variable not converting into date object in android but it works fine when i hard code the string.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        String getdate, getday, gethijri, gettimezone, getfajr, getsunrise, getduhr, getasr, getsunset, getmaghrib, getisha, getimsak;
        public static final String inputFormat = "hh:mm";
        SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
        String compareFajrOne = "";
        String compareFajrTwo = "";
        private Date date;
        private Date dateComparefajrOne;
        private Date dateComparefajrTwo;
        private Date dateCompareishaTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dailynamazrecord);
  Button  fajrofer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fajrada);
    final boolean[] ispressed = {false};
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
     final int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    final int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    date = parseDateeb(Integer.toString(hour)+":"+ Integer.toString(minute));
    dateComparefajrOne = parseDateeb(compareFajrOne);
    dateComparefajrTwo = parseDateeb(compareFajrTwo);
    fajrofer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, compareFajrOne+"\n"+compareFajrTwo+"\n"+dateComparefajrOne+"\n"+date+"\n"+dateComparefajrTwo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if ( dateComparefajrOne.before(date)&& dateComparefajrTwo.after(date)) {

                if (ispressed[0]) {
                    fajrofer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.namazoffered);

                } else {
                    fajrofer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ofeer);
                }

                ispressed[0] = !ispressed[0];
            } else {
                if (p != null)
                    showPopup(Main2Activity.this, p);
            }


        }


    });

public class FectchDetails2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String data = "";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Karachi&country=Pakistan&method=8");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONObject gtimings=json2.getJSONObject("timings");
            getfajr = gtimings.getString("Fajr");
            getsunrise = gtimings.getString("Sunrise");
            getduhr = gtimings.getString("Dhuhr");
            getasr = gtimings.getString("Asr");
            getsunset = gtimings.getString("Sunset");
            getmaghrib = gtimings.getString("Maghrib");
            getisha = gtimings.getString("Isha");
            getimsak = gtimings.getString("Imsak");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        compareStringOne=getfajr.toString();
        compareStringTwo=getsunrise.toString();

    }
}




private Date parseDateeb(String date) {

    try {

        return   inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }

}
}
```

String time passed from `AsyncTask` class variable not converting into date object in android but it works fine when i hard code the sting.
like:
`String compareFajrOne = "05:18";`
`String compareFajrTwo = "06:40";`
Kindly guide me i just want to check that current time is in the range of given times

Comment: post your related full code. its not clear yet what you are doing

Comment: see below here is my code

Comment: where are you calling to `FectchDetails2` to execute ?

Comment: i called it on onCreate in above code that line was missed